# Regex - Get all words that are not wrapped with a "/"

Tags: c#, regex, string

Im really trying to learn regex so here it goes.

I would really like to get all words in a string which do not have a "/" on either side.
For example, I need to do this to:
"Hello Great /World/"
I need to have the results:
"Hello"
"Great"

is this possible in regex, if so, how do I do it? I think i would like the results to be stored in a string array :)

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use this regular expression `\b(?<!/)\w+(?!/)\b`:

```
var str = "Hello Great /World/ /I/ am great too";
var words = Regex.Matches(str, @"\b(?<!/)\w+(?!/)\b")
    .Cast<Match>()
    .Select(m=>m.Value)
    .ToArray();
```

This will get you:

```
Hello
Great
am
great
too
```

Comment: @Code Jockey, the OP said *do not have a `/` on either side*, so this should produce the correct results

Comment: @user1290653 and @ Alex not how I interpreted it - but apparently, how the OP interpreted it... :) -- shame, 'cuz I had that LOOONG ago, but struggling with a solution to my interpretation -- just hope OP doesn't want to match either `Bob` or `Sally` in `send the /message/ to Bob/Sally right /away/, please`

Comment: yes I considered this, I was going to get the basic thing going and then sort out the rest

Comment: @user1290653 and @ Alex I am fairly certain I interpreted this way because the title used the word "wrapped" (which to me means on all sides, or in the case of a _line_ of text, _both_ sides). Regardless, I have a solution to my interpretation, should you want to consider it for selection.

Answer (score 2):

```
 var newstr = Regex.Replace("Hello Great /World/", @"/(\w+?)/", "");
```

If you realy want an array of strings

```
var words = Regex.Matches(newstr, @"\w+")
    .Cast<Match>()
    .Select(m => m.Value)
    .ToArray();
```

Comment: This could lead to extra spaces in the final string (example "Hello Great /World/ /I/ am great too"). Just make sure when splitting the string into an array that you ignore empty strings.

Answer (score 1):

I would first split the string into the array, then filter out matching words. This solution might also be cleaner than a big regexp, because you can spot the requirements for "word" and the filter better.

The big regexp solution would be something like word boundary - not a slash - many no-whitespaces - not a slash - word boundary.

Comment: add each word into an array and if the word doesnt contain a "/" then add it? thats exactly what i want really

Answer (score 0):

I would use a regex replace to replace all /[a-zA-Z]/ with '' (nothing) then get all words

Comment: i dont want the words that are contained in the "/" though

Comment: that's why you have to replace them with empty string (aka: removing those)

Comment: better replace [a-zA-Z] with \w+?

Answer (score 0):

**Try this one :** ([Click here for a demo](http://regexr.com?30jbs))

```
(\s(?<!/)([A-Za-z]+)(?!/))|((?<!/)([A-Za-z]+)(?!/)\s)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using this example excerpt:

> The /character/ "_" (underscore/under-strike) can be /used/ in /variable/ names /in/ many /programming/ /languages/, while the /character/ "/" (slash/stroke/solidus) is typically not allowed.

...this expression matches any string of letters, numbers, underscores, or apostrophes (fairly typical idea of a "word" in English) that does not have a `/` character *both* before *and* after it - `wrapped with a "/"`

```
\b([\w']+)\b(?<=(?<!/)\1|\1(?!/))
```

...and is the purest form, using only one character class to define "word" characters. It matches the example as follows:

```
Matched               Not Matched
-------------         -------------
The                   character
_                     used
underscore            variable
under                 in
strike                programming
can                   languages
be                    character
in                    stroke
names
many
while
the
slash
solidus
is
typically
not
allowed
```

If excluding `/stroke/`, is not desired, then adding a bit to the end limitation will allow it, depending upon how you want to define the beginning of a "next" word:

```
\b([\w']+)\b(?<=(?<!/)\1|\1(?!/([^\w]))).
```

changes `(?!/)` to `(?!/([^\w]))`, which allows `/something/` *if it does have* a letter, number, or underscore immediately after it. This would move `stroke` from the "Not Matched" to the "Matched" list, above.

*note: `\w` matches uppercase or lowercase letters, numbers and the underscore character*

If you want to alter your concept for "word" from the above, simply exchange the characters and shorthand character classes contained in the `[\w']` part of the expression to something like `[a-zA-Z']` to exclude digits or `[\w'-]` to include hyphens, which would capture `under-strike` as a single match, rather than two separate matches:

```
\b([\w'-]+)\b(?<=(?<!/)\1|\1(?!/([^\w])))
```

---

***IMPORTANT ALTERNATIVE!!!*** *(I think)*

I just thought of an alternative to *Matching* any words that *are not* wrapped with `/` symbols: simply *consume* all of these symbols and words that *are* surrounded in them (splitting). This has a few benefits: no lookaround means this could be used in more contexts (JavaScript does not support lookbehind and some flavors of regex don't support lookaround at all) while increasing efficiency; also, using a split expression means a direct result of a String array:

```
string input = "The /character/ "_" (underscore/under-strike) can be..."; //etc...
string[] resultsArray = Regex.Split(input, @"([^\w'-]+?(/[\w]+/)?)+");
```

voila!